# Django Filtering across models

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I need to filter timeline post entries based on whether a user is following the author of the post or not (just like FB). How to achieve this using filters

models.py

```
class Timeline_Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    text = models.TextField()

class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                  related_name='rel_from_set',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                related_name='rel_to_set',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)


User.add_to_class('following',
                  models.ManyToManyField('self',
                                         through=Contact,
                                         related_name='followers',
                                         symmetrical=False))
```

views.py

```
class TimelinePostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TimelinePostSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Timeline_Post.objects.all()
        request_queries = self.request.query_params
        if(request_queries):
            user = request_queries.get('user', None)
            return Timeline_Post.objects.filter(author = user)
        return Timeline_Post.objects.filter( ???   )
```

Comment: `Timeline_Post.objects.filter(author__followers=user)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Timeline_Post.objects.filter(
    author__followers=user
)
```

with *`user`* the user that is supposed to be following the `author` of that `Timeline_Post`, so probably `self.request.user`.